# qtserialport in c++ app ubuntu

Tags: c++, qml

Can someone please tell me how to install the qtserialport to use in a c++ project in ubuntu?
Thanks.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=QtSerialPort&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 14.04-20.04 QtSerialPort is provided by the *libqt5serialport5-dev* package from the default Ubuntu repositories.